# Is there a command-line javadoc query tool?

Tags: java, command-line, javadoc

I want to improve my auto-complete ability in emacs to include javadoc support.  Assuming that I have source jars for everything, is there a tool I can use to query the source jars for javadoc data?  The output format isn't too important as it can probably be massaged a bit.

So the input to the tool is a classpath and a class name, and some options, just like `javap`

Comment: if the output format isn't too important, why not try javadoc? it generates html for you right? didn't get what you want.

Comment: @Kent he obviously is one of the emacs maniacs who pimp up emacs until it exceeds Eclipse´s feature set. Thus, he wants autocomplete and so on in emacs. (This comment is not meant to be as mean as it reads.)

Comment: @Kent I just want a very tiny subset of the javadoc output, say for a specific field in a class.  Can it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if vim could do it, would you go with it? :P

after a quick search, I found that javaDoc uses Doclet to generate html javadocs.

package info of Doclet:

> The Doclet API (also called the Javadoc API) provides a mechanism for
>   clients to inspect the source-level structure of programs and
>   libraries, including javadoc comments embedded in the source.

And you could check Doclet api for detail. I am afraid that you have to write your own command-line tool (java program) to get the javadoc comments.

Doclet API:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec/index.html

Taglet API you may want to take a look too.

> Taglet API is an interface provided for custom formatting the text of
>   Javadoc tags.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/guide/javadoc/taglet/spec/com/sun/tools/doclets/Taglet.html

And just curious, you want to do auto-compeletion why you need javaDoc? I thought you need tags of java source codes.  well I am not an emacs 
user, ignore it if it was a stupid question.

Comment: This is what I found as well, but I don't want to create an utility in java for this.  I'll tag this as correct if there is no such tool as I suspect.  Btw, javadoc is nice when you want to auto-complete to get some information about the symbols you are choosing amongst.

Comment: @user239558 then what you need is not auto-completion, actually it is a sort of online help. like this? (python) http://blog.dispatched.ch/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/436x312xomnicompletion.png.pagespeed.ic.EZGVK8suHn.png

Comment: yes that's exactly it.  While auto-completing, you get some more information about the various methods, not just the name of the method.  I still think this is within the scope of "auto-complete", but you're totally on-spot with your image.

Comment: I will accept this answer.  But since there really isn't such a tool, I've implemented the required functionality using google.el, url.el, and the w3m renderer.  I fetch the javadoc html output from the web using google and url, and render the correct section using w3m.  Fortunately, the javadoc output has standard naming conventions for anchor names in the output that I use.